# parsing xml in java with inconsistent tags

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file in java using the DOM parser and its working fine. 
The issue i am having is that i get an error if a tag is not consistent. For example I have an xml file as follows

```
<employee>
<employeeid></employeeid>
<name></name>
<secondname></secondname>
</employee>
<employee>
<employeeid></employeeid>
<name></name>
<secondname></secondname>
</employee>
<employee>
<employeeid></employeeid>
<secondname></secondname>
</employee>
```

Because the name tag is missing in the last element i get an error but if i put it in it works fine. Is there any way of fixing this?

System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
            doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

```
NodeList listOfCourses = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
int totalCourses = listOfCourses.getLength();
System.out.println("Total no of courses : " + totalCourses);

for(int s=0; s<listOfCourses.getLength() ; s++){


    Node firstCourseNode = listOfCourses.item(s);
    if(firstCourseNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){


        Element firstCourseElement = (Element)firstCourseNode;

        //-------
        NodeList employeeList = firstCourseElement.getElementsByTagName("employeeId");
        Element employeeElement = (Element)employeeList.item(0);


        NodeList textFNList = employeeElement.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("CourseId : " + 
               ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

        //-------
        NodeList titleList = firstCourseElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
        Element titleElement = (Element)titleList.item(0);

        NodeList textLNList = titleElement.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("Title : " + 
               ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

        //----
        NodeList descriptionList = firstCourseElement.getElementsByTagName("secondname");
        Element ageElement = (Element)descriptionList.item(0);

        NodeList textdescrList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("Description : " + 
               ((Node)textdescrList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using for parsing ?

Comment: the code is as follows , ive left out the document builder factory

Comment: just edited question there